# Best way to add p-trap under my kitchen sink when drain goes down into slab

Tags: plumbing

I just bought a 1980's condo, and there is no p-trap under the kitchen sink.  The drain is down into the slab.  It's a 50/50 sink with a disposal on the left.  Is a p-trap still needed with this vertical drain?  Thank you.

Comment: You can buy a usb camera for cheap and send it down the pipe to see if there is a P trap in the slab or not.

Comment: Renting an inspection cam (or asking a plumber to do the same) sounds like the safest bet.  You or your plumber *might* be able to "feel out" a trap with a snake, but that's probably not as reliable as the camera.

Comment: If it's a condo, maybe ask the neighbors if you can look under their sinks for clues.

Answer (score 1):

If there is already a trap underground, you won't need a trap under the sink - indeed if you added one, you will have major problems with draining with a double-trapped setup.

Comment: Yep.  And there is my dilemma.  i know of no way to tell if there is already one underground.  But i did not think that was ever done.  Are p-traps sometimes installed in the slab?

Comment: Not usually, but I've seen that pretty much anything is possible! If it isn't trapped, I'd expect you'd soon notice the drain smell in the room.